# Understanding my install.log file

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

I've just cracked my install.log file(s) for the first time and I could use some help understanding the anatomy of the file. The thing I need to understand is the significance of the bracketed number.

Example:

`Jun  5 08:16:13 My-MacBook-Pro Installer[2605]`

It appears that each number applies to a specific install. Is this true? And how is the number generated?

Another question that would help me... How would you have tagged this question?

Thanks for helping out a newbie!

Comment: I just added a "PackageMaker" tag, to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the process id number (pid) of the installer.

$ ps auxww | grep -i install

user 82649   0.0  0.3  1047576  12176   ??  S     3:19PM   0:00.27 /System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer -psn_0_7882628

From /var/log/install.log

May  7 15:20:30 My-MacBook-Pro Installer[82649]: User picked Standard Install